# Kotlin flow emits but collect is not receiving

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have this basic flow emit / collect code but collect is not receiving any emits.

```
object TodoRepository {
    fun getTodos(): Flow<List<Todo>> = flow {
        val data = KtorClient.httpClient.use {
            it.get("...")
        }
        val todos = data.body<List<Todo>>()
        emit(todos) // << emit is called
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}

class TodoViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val response = MutableSharedFlow<List<Todo>>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            TodoRepository.getTodos().collect {
                // NEVER INVOKED !!!
                response.emit(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private val todoViewModel: TodoViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        runBlocking {
            todoViewModel.response.collect {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining it is never collected? Your runBlocking code will lock the main thread forever (until the app crashes with ANR) since calling collect on an infinite flow (as all SharedFlows are) means it will never frame.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks, runBlocking was the problem, after changing that to `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch` it works.

Comment: You should use lifecycleScope, though, to avoid memory leaks automatically.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sir can u help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049173/flow-re-colocting-using-repeatonlifecycle-api

Comment: @rysv can u help me :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049173/flow-re-colocting-using-repeatonlifecycle-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tenfour04 comment. `runBlocking` was the problem. For example, this will work

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        todoViewModel.response.collect {
        }
    }
```